# Is there an equivalent of lsusb for OS X

Tags: macos, usb, darwin, lsusb

This question seems to be all over google, but the answers all point to using System Profiler. That's nice, but with System Profiler all you get is something that looks like this:

```
            DasKeyboard:

              Product ID: 0x1919
              Vendor ID: 0x04d9  (Holtek Semiconductor, Inc.)
              Version: 1.06
              Speed: Up to 1.5 Mb/sec
              Location ID: 0x1d114000 / 11
              Current Available (mA): 500
              Current Required (mA): 100

            USB2.0 Hub:

              Product ID: 0x0608
              Vendor ID: 0x05e3  (Genesys Logic, Inc.)
              Version: 32.98
              Speed: Up to 480 Mb/sec
              Location ID: 0x1d113000 / 10
              Current Available (mA): 500
              Current Required (mA): 100

                Microsoft Basic Optical Mouse v2.0 :

                  Product ID: 0x00cb
                  Vendor ID: 0x045e  (Microsoft Corporation)
                  Version: 1.99
                  Speed: Up to 1.5 Mb/sec
                  Manufacturer: Microsoft 
                  Location ID: 0x1d113200 / 12
                  Current Available (mA): 500
                  Current Required (mA): 100
```

That's great if all you want are the contents of a bunch of device descriptors, but `lsusb` gives you *so* much more - information on interfaces and endpoints, interface associations, composite devices... where can you find this information in OS X? There *must* be a tool that does this?

Comment: If you don't mind, how are you using information like "interfaces and endpoints, interface associations, composite devices"?

Answer (score 204):

I got tired of forgetting the `system_profiler SPUSBDataType` syntax, so I made an `lsusb` alternative. You can find it [here](https://github.com/jlhonora/lsusb) , or install it with homebrew:

```
brew install lsusb
```

Comment: Nice script! Would you like to add it as homebrew formula? This would be convenient.

Comment: That's a nice utility, but it's still just a fraction of what lsusb on linux can get you. lsusb on linux can give you the full contents of the device's configuration descriptors. Without that, I'm afraid this tool is mostly just a pretty-printer.

Comment: May be limited, but it does exactly what I needed. Makes my development environment consistent with just a `brew install` Thank you!!

Comment: That's a nice script, but it really shouldn't be called "lsusb" considering what `lsusb` can actually do: https://askubuntu.com/a/604169/598643

Comment: A neat one would be `alias lsusb='system_profiler SPUSBDataType'` if you don't care too much about getting the exact same result for lsusb

Comment: Funny how the most obvious answer is often the least plausible one.

Answer (score 113):

I typically run this command to list USB devices on macOS, along with details about them:

```
ioreg -p IOUSB -l -w 0
```

Comment: See my response to @blekenbleu about ioreg

Comment: Copy of comment by [Ted Middleton](https://stackoverflow.com/users/134692): The problem is that ioreg and IORegistryExplorer show you the kernel objects that have been matched to devices, not details of the devices themselves. That means you won't see interfaces on configurations other than the currently active one, and you won't see any endpoint information at all (which is the most useful output from lsusb).

Comment: The manpages seem to have been removed. Alternates (as of May 2019) are: https://www.unix.com/man-page/mojave/8/ioreg/ and http://www.manpagez.com/man/8/ioreg/

Answer (score 52):

Homebrew users: you can get `lsusb` by installing [`usbutils` formula](https://formulae.brew.sh/formula/usbutils) from my tap:

```
brew install usbutils
```

It installs the REAL `lsusb` based on Linux sources (version 007).

Comment: Finally, the real deal. I can confirm that this one works on OX 10.13.6.

Comment: Thanks, this is a much better solution, unavailable at the time I developed the `lsusb` script.

Comment: Thanks, @jlhonora. The irony is that Homebrew guys decided to add your `lsusb` script to `homebrew-core`, instead of my `usbutils`.

Comment: You can always send them a PR.

Comment: Source: https://github.com/mikhailai/homebrew-misc/blob/master/usbutils.rb

Comment: linking fails, I had to manually link it: `ln -s /usr/local/Cellar/usbutils/007/bin/lsusb ~/bin/lsusb`

Comment: With bintray having been sunset, the binary distribution is no longer available (download fails with a 403).  Installling from source works however, use `brew install -s usbutils`

Comment: Now the binary distribution is available from the official homebrew/core repo. Simply use `brew install usbutils` and do not use mikhailai's tap (which is trying to download from the dead bintray).

Comment: it doesn't work at all! This **`lsusb` shows only a single device** whereas all the other commands shows lots of devices. I've tried both `brew install usbutils` and `brew install -s usbutils`, same behavior. Besides tree doesn't work, it simply says `lsusb -t is only supported on Linux`. `lsusb --version` returns `lsusb (usbutils) 015`

Answer (score 17):

In mac osx , you can use the following command:

```
system_profiler SPUSBDataType
```

Comment: system_profiler has the same problem as ioreg - it reflects the state of kernel objects that the kernel has matched to devices, not the devices themselves. I want something that will basically display the full layout of the device, as in what's in all the configuration descriptors of all configurations.

Answer (score 7):

If  you are a user of [MacPorts](https://www.macports.org/), you may simply install [usbutils](https://www.macports.org/ports.php?by=name&substr=usbutils)

```
sudo port install usbutils
```

If you are not, this might be a good opportunity to install it, it has ports for several other useful linux tools.

Comment: Ah - ok, in the port file I see, "depends_lib port:libusb", and the source does indeed seem to require libusb. That would do it, I guess. I don't really use macports, though - I'm on brew. And I'd hate to have to install macports just for this, especially when lsusb could be reimplemented with user-space iokit so easily.

Comment: This should be the accepted answer. Howerver, right now this package is broken because of its dependency `usbids`, track it over https://trac.macports.org/ticket/53188

Comment: That seems to have been fixed by now.

Answer (score 5):

I'll through my hat into this having tried the answers here. The `lsusb` script is barely working and the macOS port of `usbutils` doesn't capture string descriptors or support `--tree`.

It lead me to create [cyme](https://github.com/tuna-f1sh/cyme), a modern cross-platform USB list tool using `system_profiler -json` under the hood. It also uses `libusb` for extra data/cross-platform and `udev` on Linux. It supports `--lsusb` compatible mode, which near matches `lsusb`'s output for all args. It should scratch the macOS `lsusb` itch and more.

Comment: This is really good. Depth of information and great display.

Answer (score 3):

How about `ioreg`? The output's much more detailed than the profiler, but it's a bit dense.

Source: https://lists.macosforge.org/pipermail/macports-users/2008-July/011115.html

Comment: See my response to @blekenbleu. lsusb has much more information than ioreg/IORegistryExplorer, or any other program like system_profiler that just walks the iokit registry.

Answer (score 1):

At least on 10.10.5, `system_profiler SPUSBDataType` output is NOT
dynamically updated when a new USB device gets plugged in,
while `ioreg -p IOUSB -l -w 0` does.

Comment: The problem is that ioreg and IORegistryExplorer show you the kernel objects that have been matched to devices, not details of the devices themselves. That means you won't see interfaces on configurations other than the currently active one, and you won't see any endpoint information at all (which is the most useful output from lsusb).

Comment: What I'd like is a tool that would show the contents of all of a device's configurations descriptors. ioreg won't do this, lsusb does.

Comment: I don't see how this is different from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29778245/589259)?

Answer (score 1):

On Mac OS X, the Xcode developer suite includes the USB Proper.app application.  This is found in /Developer/Applications/Utilities/.  USB Prober will allow you to examine the device and interface descriptors.

Comment: Xcode.app/Contents/Applications/Utilities doesn't exist in Xcode 8.3, and there's no USB Prober in Applications.  I do know that USB Prober is still available but I haven't yet been able to find out where it is.  It's inside a package with some other tools.

Comment: It is an extra developer tool to download: https://download.developer.apple.com/Developer_Tools/hardware_io_tools_for_xcode__february_2012/hardware_io_tools_for_xcode.dmg